# Convert Persian HTML to PDF

Tags: pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, tuespechkin

When converting a html file with Persian content, the result does not contain appropriate Persian content. All Persian content shows as `???`

Answer (score 2):

Are you starting your HTML with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
```

Also ensure that the Persian fonts are installed locally.

Comment: Yes but this is not effect on the pdf file

Comment: It seams, Pdf has problem with Persian and Arabic Content

Comment: 2019 and still problem exists

Answer (score 0):

now you can solve your problem by using **itext7.pdfhtml** and **itext7.pdfcalligraph**.
install them using NuGet manager,
and use this method to convert your Persian or Arabic Html to pdf :

```
public static void ConvertHtmlToPDF(string Html)
{
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        FontProvider fontProvider = new DefaultFontProvider();
        properties.SetFontProvider(fontProvider);

        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(new FileStream(PDFFileAddressTobeGenerated, FileMode.Create));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);

        HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(htmlFile, pdfDocument, properties);
}
```